# Can't understand why my Angular Dependencies aren't resolving?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why are my modules not available to the $injector service? Console is reporting 'unknown provider' for both my `baseHello` and `geoHello` services. Obviously I have missed something fundamental, but for the life-of-me I can't see it!

http://plnkr.co/edit/3Y0WeIH1dCkWKMhRJKnM?p=preview

```
/**Modules, we flesh these out below**/
angular.module('demo.services',[]);
angular.module('demo.directives',['demo.services']);
angular.module('demo',['demo.services','demo.directives']);

/**Application Module, Dependency on geoHello Service**/
angular.module('demo')
.controller('myCtrl',['$scope', 'geoHello',function($scope,geoHello){
  $scope.test = geoHello.msg
}]);

/**Base Hello Service**/
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("baseHello",function(r){
  return{
    'msg': 'Hello from ...'
  }
});

/**Service With Dependency on baseHello**/
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("geoHello",['baseHello',function(baseHello){
  var msg = baseHello.msg.replace("...","world");
  return{
    'msg': msg
  }
}]);

/**Directive With Dependency on geoHello**/
angular.module("demo.directives")
.directive('ngDemo',['geoHello',function(geoHello){
  return{
    'template': geoHello.msg
  }
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document,['demo']);
```

Comment: In general, it helps when you debug with a non-minimized version of angularjs. You would have discovered the unresolved dependency on `r` as suggested below quickly.

Comment: Looking back at my console the original error indicated the 'r' dependency, my eyes kept focusing on the other two dependnecies in the the indicated chain within the error message. It was right in front of me the whole time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an unresolved dependency (r) in your factory definition `baseHello`

```
/**Base Hello Service**/
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("baseHello",function(r){
  return{
    'msg': 'Hello from ...'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think **you have a typo** in your code. You have a dependency for the `baseHello` service called `r` which is not resolveable. It is not necessary as you do not seem to use it, so if you take it out then your code will run in your Plunker.

**Before:**

```
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("baseHello",function(r){
  return{
    'msg': 'Hello from ...'
  }
});
```

**After:**

```
angular.module("demo.services")
.factory("baseHello",function(){
  return{
    'msg': 'Hello from ...'
  }
});
```

See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8jI2EaecWEXryJfU1qKU) for a working Plunker.